# Git push command, error encountered -fatal: invalid refspec 'https://github.......git'

Tags: git, push, refspec

I'm in the `master` branch and have added the remote branch, after which I'm unable to push the data from local to remote.:

```
$ Git remote add master https://....git

$ Git push origin master https:// ...git
Fatal: invalid refspec 'https://...git'
```

Answer (score 9):

You should "[git remote add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem)" `origin`, not `master`:

```
git remote add origin https://...
git remote remove master
git push -u origin master
```

If you *already* add a remote `origin`, then fix it with [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem), instead of `git remote add`:

```
git remote set-url origin https://...
```

Comment: I tried this. but I got the "error: remote origin already exists". How do I solve this ?

Comment: @VedantKakade Good point. I have edited the answer to address that use case.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by changing the authentication method from HTTPS to SSH.

Guide for Github SSH keys: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Create a new SSH key in github (https://github.com/settings/keys)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with gitlab and what helped me in this case, was adding additional option `--push-option=ci-skip` and putting at the end `HEAD:<branchname>` like below

```
git checkout -b ${newbranch}
#..<do  your stuff>..
#..<add and commit>...
git push --push-option=ci-skip http://${SERVER_HOST}/${PROJECT_PATH}.git/ HEAD:${newbranch}
```